# How to update an attribute value in xml file based on the node value using xsltproc

Tags: xslt

I have below xml file-

```
<APP_PACK_CONFIG>
    <APP_PACK_ID>X1</APP_PACK_ID>
    <APP_PACK_NAME>DEF</APP_PACK_NAME>
    <APP_PACK_DESCRIPTION>DEF</APP_PACK_DESCRIPTION>
    <VERSION>1.2.3.4.5</VERSION>
    <APP>
        <APP_ID PREREQ="" DEF_SEL_FLG="YES" ENABLE="YES">ABC_XYZ</APP_ID>
        <APP_NAME>Application for XYZ</APP_NAME>
        <APP_DESCRIPTION>XYZ</APP_DESCRIPTION>
        <VERSION>1.2.3.4.5</VERSION>
    </APP>
    <APP>
        <APP_ID PREREQ="ABC_XYZ" ENABLE="">ABC_DEF</APP_ID>
        <APP_NAME>DEF</APP_NAME>
        <APP_DESCRIPTION>Application for DEF</APP_DESCRIPTION>
        <VERSION>1.2.3.4.5</VERSION>
    </APP>
</APP_PACK_CONFIG>
```

I have to set ENABLE="YES" if the parameter I am passing matches node value i.e. ABC_DEF.

I have tried below xsl stylesheet to achieve this but I am unable to get the expected result. I am very new at xslt and trying to use this for one of the utility i am building which needs to modify this xml file based on user input. Please suggest what should I do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> 
<xsl:param name="appID" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="APP_PACK_CONFIG/APP/APP_ID">
        <xsl:if test="text()=$appID">
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="ENABLE">
                <xsl:value-of select="YES"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am running the stylesheet as below-

```
xsltproc -o ./$3_PACK_TMP.xml --stringparam appID $app ./enableApp_TMP.xsl ./$3_PACK.xml
```

Comment: Ideally you could just use `<xsl:template match="APP_PACK_CONFIG/APP/APP_ID[. = $appID]/@ENABLE">`, that should do in XSLT 2 and later. Unfortunately in XSLT 1 the use of variable references in patterns is not allowed so you will need to match on `<xsl:template match="APP_PACK_CONFIG/APP/APP_ID/@ENABLE">` and output the attribute value with an `xsl:choose/xsl:when test="[.. = $appID]"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I tried the solution provided by you but instead of updating the ENABLE attribute to YES it is removing the attribute from xml file. Please suggest if I am doing something wrong. Here is the template I tried- `<xsl:template match="APP_PACK_CONFIG/APP/APP_ID/@ENABLE">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(.. = $appID)">
   <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:attribute name="ENABLE">
    <xsl:value-of select="YES"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: See the posted answer, I have tried to outline there how the template should look.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I had in mind when I posted the comment:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> 
    <xsl:param name="appID" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="APP_PACK_CONFIG/APP/APP_ID/@ENABLE">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".. = $appID">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">YES</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>      
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin. It works just fine as I needed.